# Another crypto-limerick, this time from Verdun

Tags: cipher, limerick

Traditionally, after the [limerick from Peru](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12623/a-crypto-limerick-from-peru) comes one with even fewer lines revealed:

> There once was a man from Verdun,
>   Ekptl hkndekbmq eff oopqvodw ro gkhl uhr.
>   Ol onrh lts r fbel,
>   Gash ona hrm kh Odez,
>   Rmw bshobrodw onmp qpah lsa gzh.

Can you figure out what encryption method is being used on the second line (since I'm sure you've figured out by now what the plaintext is), and use that knowledge to figure out how this Verdunnian man's limerick went?

Note: each line is  encrypted separately, and it's not a Vigenère cipher this time around.

> The key is a writer of complete nonsense.

Comment: what, Edward Lear?

Comment: Joe Z. i don't think you're playing fair, oopqvodw  has 1 letter to many

Comment: It's a traditional mark of the Playfair cipher to insert an "x" between double letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it took me way to long but I got it :)

First the hint (which was highly necessary to decrypt it)

> The key is a writer of complete nonsense.

$ $

> This is pretty literal (pun intended) since it referred to [Edward Lear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Lear), the author of a book titled *The Complete Nonsense of Edward Lear*, a book full of limericks. So let's assume that **EdwardLear** is the key.

So now we have the key but what then?

> Well we start trying ciphers, I tried to use a program for this but in the end decided to use [Rumkin](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/), sure i had to do it by hand for the ciphers it has but at least I knew it'd go as I wanted.
>  Once I'd tried some I came to the Playfair cipher and finally I saw the text I wanted: `Whose limericks all stopxped at line one` well almost the x shouldn't be there.

Then it was quite trivial to get the rest:

> He then got a clue 
>  From the man in Peru 
>  And completed this poem for fun

Though i do not know why:

> we had to translate the letter J into I, if there had been such a clue i would have sooner thought about a play fair cipher. Even P (peru) into V (verdun) would have made more sense to me.

Comment: So, you used http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php ? I tried to insert "Ekptl hkndekbmq eff oopqvodw ro gkhl uhr." into it, but got nothing relevant. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @leoll2 did you set it to decrypt?

Comment: Playfair: decrypt mode, translate J into I, encode double, blank alphabet key, message "Ekptl hkndekbmq eff oopqvodw ro gkhl uhr". 
What I get is "Zeoun fhpcdgelr aki lnolqiyr mm iigp qgs"

Comment: @leoll2 well ofcourse you need the key, sorry was i not clear: "Edward Lear" should be the key? I've edited my answer to make it more clear hopefully, if not feel free to adjust it for readability

Comment: The stuff about inserting X between double letters and transcribing J into I are all quirks of the cipher itself. I haven't done anything nonstandard.

Comment: @JoeZ. what site/program did you use for encrypting the text?

Comment: I used Rumkin like you did. Although I disabled the "Encode double letters" part and manually inserted the X's because the post above mentioned it and the alternative standard for encoding double letters was somewhat iffy.

Comment: @JoeZ. The X is for obsucirty so pp wouldn't transorm into vv. but the text is split up into pairs like this: li me ri ck sa ll st op pe da tl in eo ne. Here you see stopped is split like st op pe da, so you see there is no pp, but there is at all though (double ll). For as  far as the tranlate J into I is conserned, I have no idea what this does but some hint to it in the puzzle might be nice to make it fit more. Anyway it was a good one, even though i personally find looking for a cipher when there are no clues to the cipher a bit tedious.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat: You forgot the "whose" at the beginning of the line. That shifts the "pp" so they're in line with each other.

Comment: And translating J into I makes it so that there are only 25 letters to encode, and so it fits neatly into a 5-by-5 matrix.

Comment: @JoeZ. O :P well.. xD And i did not know. thanks, but then maybe some clue would have been nice.

Comment: A clue would have been nice, perhaps, but in this case I clued you into everything _but_ the encryption algorithm, which was basically the "crypto-challenge" of the problem (find out which cipher is being used). I could have clued in "Playfair" and then not given a clue to the key, perhaps, but I don't know if that would have had a unique solution or not.

Comment: @JoeZ. you can be sure with crypto there will be only 1 solution which makes sense :P Anyway, looking forward to the next one :) (still can't figure out your AES limerick)